# Trouble with List/Interface

Tags: java, compilation, compiler-errors, java.util.scanner

I cannot get my contact list program to work. I have 3 classes: main(), contact(), contactlist().

My main problem is that I want to have my main() print a menu and have it control the navigation. I am tempted to write a method in Contactlist() but I want to perform this task in main().

I have created a basic skeleton code that I am sure is wrong in many ways. I am having some trouble with my List interface.

Getting an error in ContactList: `List<Contact> contacts;`

In Contact.java, getContactBylName method is getting an error as well.

Main()

```
//Main class for contact list
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   }
}
```

Contact()

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

//Class implemented by ContactList
public class Contact implements ContactList {

String fName;
String lName;
String email;
String streetAdd;
String zipCode;

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//Constructor
public Contact (String fName, String lName, String email, String streetAdd, String zipCode) {

}

//implementation for adding contact
public void addContact(Contact contact) {
    contacts.add(contact);
}
//implementation for printing contact list
public void printContacts(Contact contact) {

    }

//implementation for getting contact by last name
public void getContactBylName(String lName) {
    System.out.println("Enter a last name to search:");
    lName = scan.nextLine();

    if (ContactList.lName == lName) {
        return Contact;
        }

//implementation for getting contact by email
public void getContactByemail(String email) {
    System.out.println("Enter an email to search:");
    email = scan.nextLine();

    if (ContactList.email == email) {
        return Contact;
        }
}
public void getContactByzipCode(String zipCode) {

}
}
```

ContactList()

```
//Class implementing list Contact
import java.util.List;

public interface ContactList {

 List<Contact> contacts;

 contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

 //method to add contact
void addContact(Contact contact);

//method to print contact list
void printContacts(Contact contact);

//method to get a contact by last name
void getContactBylName(String lName);

//method to get a contact by email address
void getContactByemail(String email);

//method to get all contacts in a zip code
void getContactByzipCode(String zipCode);
}
```

Comment: "Getting an error" suggests you have an error message - please tell us what it is. *Always* include error messages in your questions.

Comment: List<Contact> contacts; says Syntax error on token ";",, expected              
Error in my getContactBylName says lName cannot be resolved or is not a field

Comment: in java, classes can't have brackets, so it's **impossible** you have classes called `Main()`, `Contacts()` and `ContactList()`. Please think before you compose your question

Comment: Sorry I am new to java, no need to be so harsh

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
public interface ContactList {
    List<Contact> contacts;
    ...
}
```

You can't declare fields (other than constants) in interfaces. An interface is the API - it's up to the *implementation* to work out whether it wants to store its data in a `List<Contact>` or something else.

Additionally, `Contact` should *not* implement `ContactList` - separate the idea of "a single contact" from "a collection of contacts". Your interface should probably *return* a `Contact` reference from each "get" method, too... so it would look something like this:

```
public interface ContactList {
    void addContact(Contact contact);    
    void printContacts();    
    Contact getContactByLastName(String lastName);    
    Contact getContactByEmail(String email);
    Contact getContactByZipCode(String zipCode);
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I not use interface? I've actually had others suggest me to use them

Comment: Why not use interfaces.But know how to use before using it.

Comment: @Marimon: I didn't suggest that you shouldn't use an interface - in fact I showed you what the interface should probably look like. But then you need two classes: one to implement the interface, and one to be the `Contact` class, which *shouldn't* implement the interface.